# HP MSA1040 To Two ESX Servers No Switches

Tags: storage, iscsi, network-attached-storage

I'm looking to buy a HP MSA1040 to use as shared storage (for HA) between two ESX hosts. I don't have a 10gbps switch of any kind in the office. Can I connect 1 of the 10gbps iSCSI to one server and the other 10gbps iSCSI to the other server. Then have the servers in a HA configuration, so I can lose an ESX host. I've heard this is only available with Fibre Channel, not iSCSI. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it without a switch. The MSA1040 support it.

See that wiring diagram;

[image]

From the example disregard the two added array, but you see two server with on MSA1040. Source; https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c04220803